# Get python defaults from sqlalchemy column metadata

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, column-defaults

I need to get python-executed expressions from sqlalchemy column metadata for all columns in all tables of my app.
I can get defaults (or server defaults) as sqlalchemy objects. They are:

- ScalarElementColumnDefault (e.g. default string for string column)
- CallableColumnDefault (e.g. uuid4 for id column)
- DefaultClause (e.g. datetime.now for created_at column)
- SqlAlchemy expressions (e.g. sa.text)
  As I know, there maybe some user typed objects.

I know how to get value from scalar element column default (property "arg"), but for the others I can't find anything useful in object's attributes.
I need to get the proper function able to calling (e.g. to get UUID from uuid4 function).
How can I get it?

This is how I get defaults as sqlalchemy objects:

```
defaults = {}
for attr_name, attr in MyModel.__dict__.items():
    if (hasattr(attr, "default") or hasattr(attr, "server_default")) and (
        attr.default is not None or attr.server_default is not None
    ):
        defaults[attr_name] = attr.default or attr.server_default
```

I do this on the initialization of the app.
After that when I try to create object in db, I want to do smth like

```
if "my_column_with_default" not in in_obj:  # in_obj is a dict with input data, dumped from pydantic model
    in_obj["my_column_with_default"] = defaults["my_column_with_default"]()
```

You'd say that sqlalchemy does this anyway without my participation, but I want to do some validation before transaction in database

UPD: DefaultClause is always the result of server_default value (callable or scalar - doesn't matter), meanwhile CallableColumnDefault appears when you pass callable as default value of the column

Comment: Yes, both CallableColumnDefault and DefaultClause accept callable, but sqlalchemy set these defaults as different objects. I don't really know why.

Comment: Like to a flush hack. But in this case I'll get all sqlalchemy exceptions as is and 500 to user. I could catch them and parse in some way, but it's a kind of dog-nail imho - and that's I dont like

Comment: particularly I want to validate unique constraints - I can't do it on the level of pydantic model if the column has server_default value for example. If I won't do this validation postgres will raise an exception if constraint is violated. Yes, I can just pass exception details to httpexception, but I want to do it more user frendly and don't bother database before the validation

Comment: Incorrect words sry. Don't insert data that violates constraints. e.g. I have object with set field-1 and unset field-2 and the table has UC for field-1/field-2 and default value for field-2. If I filter all objects with the same field-1 and empty field-2, the validation won't be correct, bc after that flush set the default value for field-2 and this new data could violate UC.

Comment: UC is for two or more columns, and only some of them can have defaults. So the concept of default is not violates constraint itself. I make lib for corporate usage and want it to cast some magic - so users (developers) doesn't have to do some extra for validation. So I want to get all defaults of all types to operate them free